# compare two variables of different length using R

Tags: r

I need to compare the values stored in two variables.The variable sizes are different. For example

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

and

```
y = c(2,6,11,12,13)
```

I need an answer that 2 and 6 are present in both variables. I need this to be done in R.Anyone help please.

Comment: Since your comment below states that you have non-integer values, you need to decide what sort of equality you're testing for.  Set theory works on numbers (or, more precisely, elements of the sets)  but computers work on approximations.   So: what are you doing, and is this homework?

Answer (score 8):

The intersect function avoids the need for @mdsumner's simple indexing:

```
> x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
> y = c(2,6,11,12,13)
> intersect(x,y)
[1] 2 6
```

Whole bunch of set operators to be found here: `help(intersect)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But in real data i have numbers with decimals(like 1.0832). I need to compare the variables and include the near by values also.Should i use round off or any other function.Example i need to include 1.0850 also when comparing it with 1.0832.

Comment: @sathya - you should make your example data representative of your real data if you want the best answers. It seems like you could `round()` or `floor()` or `ceiling()` or `trunc()` or `signif()` your data before `intersect()`ing it. Each one of those comes with it's own flavor for dealing with edge cases, one of which may be more appropriate for your data. Look at `?round` for details.

Answer (score 2):

Posted after the added requirement that some sort of tolerance be allowed: You could sequentially check one set of values against all the others in the second set or you could do it all at once with `outer()`. Once you have the outer result as a logical matrix there remains the task of referring back to the values, but expand.grid seems capable of handling that:

```
expand.grid(x,y)[outer(x,y, FUN=function(x,y) abs(x-y) < 0.01), ]
#   Var1 Var2
#2     2    2
#16    6    6
```

After posting It occurred to me that you values were sorted. Turns out that this extraction from expand.grid() survives passing unsorted vectors.

Answer (score 1):

```
x[x %in% y]
[1] 2 6
```

Or, more explicitly:

```
x[match(x, y, nomatch = 0) > 0]
[1] 2 6
```

Note that you actually chain together the results of the `match` with simple indexing into the input values.

See `?match`.